# ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\x85\x8A\x8D\x95\x97' for column 'name' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

this is the faulty statement:

```
insert into customer (id, uuid, name) values (1,uuid(), 'àèìòù');
```

I am using MySQL server 8.0.32 (just upgraded from 5.7) on Windows.

I am also executing this statement from MySQL client, on the same machine.

Same error using mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/risk?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useLocalSessionState=true&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

No error using mysql-connector-java-8.0.22 with the same environment and the same connection string.

This the table:

```
| customer | CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `uuid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_q8w2f8xfdoax44qc8w0epholu` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

And these are the variables:

```
mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                              |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                              |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                               |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                              |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                              |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                                              |
| character_sets_dir       | D:\shape\servers\mysql-8.0.32-winx64\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value              |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection          | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_database            | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server              | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe a bug? Am I missing something?

---

**update**

this is working:

```
mysql> set character_set_client=cp850;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into customer (id, uuid, name) values (1,uuid(), 'àèìòù');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

But why?

And how can I use UTF-8 also on client side?

---

**update2**

Also, commenting in `my.ini`:

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

#character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
#init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

makes JDBC working again...

Comment: tried that, not working. The only viable way seems to let the client use its own encoding, see updated question

Comment: I am using 2 different clients: JDBC (Java) and "MySQL client" from command-line. Same behavior. When **not forcing** client encoding **from the server** (disabling `character-set-client-handshake=FALSE`) the client sets up a connection and sends commands using **its own** encoding. In "MySQL Client" it is `cp850`, don't know in JDBC.

Comment: What set `character-set-server` to something different??

Comment: What OS?  In Windows, what was the charset setting for `cmd`?  For *nix, which terminal app were you using, and how does it set the charset?

Comment: Windows, as stated in Q. The cmd codepage is 850 (in my PC it is 437)

Answer (score 0):

What application are you using?

Apparently, your *client* is using "cp850" since that hex decodes to `àèìòù`.

You could either tell MySQL that you are using cp850 by establishing the connection that way, or (better) fix the encoding inside the client.

That is, the problem does not seem to be with MySQL.

**More**

If you are using Windows, did you do something like

```
chcp 850
```

Instead, you need

```
chcp 65001
```

Comment: I got the same error using either conneting with "MySQL client" from cmdline or jdbc from java (stated in question). How to fix encoding in the client? You can see the vars `character_set_client     | utf8mb4` is already fixed...

Comment: Did you type the letters into Java?  Or did the program receive the letters from some other place?

Comment: I had the problem importing a mysqldump from cmdline (mysql client). Then I tried to run the very same import from the application (running on wildfly, using JDBC), and tried also other special chars from UI.

Comment: At last I used mysql client and wrote directly a faulty statement containing `à`

Comment: codepage 850, it's default on that server machine. But that does not explain why or what's changed in the recent versions of mysqld. I used many servers with mysqld until 8.0.22 without an issue

Comment: Were any `ALTERs` performed recently?  (I have not found anything in the "changelogs" between 8.0.22 and 32.)

Comment: @MicheleMariotti - 8.0.30:  "A previous change renamed character sets having deprecated names prefixed with utf8_ to use utf8mb3_ instead. In this release, we rename the utf8_ collations as well, using the utf8mb3_ prefix; this is to make the collation names consistent with those of the character sets, not to rely any longer on the deprecated collation names, and to clarify the distinction between utf8mb3 and utf8mb4. The names using the utf8mb3_ prefix are now used exclusively for these collations in the output of SHOW statements such as SHOW CREATE TABLE, ..." -- Relevant?

Comment: " faulty statement containing à " -- more details, please.  Check the hex for `85` or `C3A0`.

Comment: Is there a charset parameter on that mysqldump call?